# Problem with matching the value

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get `strpos` to work.

If `$monthly_cost` and `$phone` are contained in the `$string` then return true.

```
<?php
$monthly_cost = 25;
$phone = "iPhone";

$string = "iPhone £25 24m Upgrade";

if (strpos($string, $phone) && strpos($string, $monthly_cost)) {
  echo "found";
}
?>
```

Or is it better to use regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (strpos($string, $phone) !== false && 
    strpos($string, $monthly_cost) !== false) {
  echo "found";
}
```

Now it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user: Change this `$monthly_cost = 25;` to `$monthly_cost = '25';`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use strpos but remember that you must use:

```
if (strpos($string, $phone)!==false && strpos($string, $monthly_cost)!==false) {
  echo "found";
}
```

because if it returns 0 the condition fails. Anyway with strpos you can only check if those values are inside the string but you can't check for example if they are complete words so if you search "25" and the string contains "256" strpos will return true, so if you need to do that type of validation you must use a regexp.

Comment: It didnt return true for some reason?

Comment: strpos does not return true or false, it returns the position of the second string inside the first one and false if it's not contained. So if $string starts with $phone then strpos returns 0 that is equal to false if you don't compare it with !==

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (strpos($string, $phone) !== false && strpos($string, $monthly_cost) !== false) {
```

strpos may return 0 if the string you are searching for is at position 0